# How to place multiple formats on the clipboard?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, clipboard

For example, what Wordpad did when I press "Ctrl+C"? 
It places many different format to clipboard. So Notepad can get the text without any color or font...etc, and you still can keep the original format when you paste in another Wordpad window.

The MSDN said I should call SetClipboardData multiple times. But it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Why not post some of the code that "doesn't work at all"?

Comment: Yes, and also tell us the manner in which it failed (program crashed, did nothing, produced different output than you expected, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Delphi's [`TClipboard.SetAsHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Clipbrd.TClipboard.SetAsHandle) to put data on the clipboard in as many formats as you want. Open the clipboard first, or else each call to `SetAsHandle` will clobber whatever else was already there, even in other formats.

```
Clipboard.Open;
Clipboard.SetAsHandle(cf_Text, x);
Clipboard.SetAsHandle(cf_Bitmap, y);
Clipboard.Close;
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have fixed this problem as you suggested. I'm using SetBuffer method of the TClipboard, the problem is that I open/close the clipboard for each call of SetBuffer.

Answer (score 3):

All modern programs use OleSetClipboard to publish clipboard formats and data.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692707%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: perhaps most, but certainly not all as not a single application I've looked into has used this interface.